# How to use background activity while dialog is pop-up

Tags: dialog

I make a activity that shows progress after clicking button. and I shows that progress Bar in dialog using Theme.Dialog. so, my question is how can I use that button continuously to shows progress. In my case at 1st click dialog gone and then I can use button. I want to make background activity activate.

Comment: what language are you using (add a tag)? and please show some code.